# Obtaining the number of standard seconds in a minute with JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to obtain an integer, long or double that represents the number of standard seconds contained in a given number of standard minutes.

```
1 minute => 60 seconds
2 minutes => 120 seconds
..
```

What is the preferred way of obtaining the number of standard seconds within a minute using JodaTime?

So far, I've been using this:

```
Minutes.minutes(2).toStandardSeconds().getSeconds()
```

I find ".getSeconds()" to be slightly redundant.

In C#, I would have used

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalSeconds
```

Is there something similar in JodaTime?

Comment: Note that in .NET you'd then need to cast from `double` to `int`, assuming you wanted an integer... I would personally live with what you've got there. Or use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` (not in Joda Time, but fine here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeConstants`. Specifically, you can use `DateTimeConstants.SECONDS_PER_MINUTE`

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
System.out.println(DateTimeConstants.SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
```

Read more about available constants [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html)..

Comment: Looks like the link is not valid. Fixed link: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html